# How to get geolocation with vue and vue2-leaflet?

Tags: vue.js, geolocation, leaflet, vue2leaflet

I'm working with vue2-leaflet. I want center property on user current location. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

I've tried already with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in mounted() with v-if on map component that show the map once the api call is completed. But it looks like is not working.

```js
<template>
  <div class="map" v-if="gettingLocation">
    <l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
      <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
      <l-marker :lat-lng="getCoords">
        <l-icon :icon-url="icon" :icon-size="iconSize"></l-icon>
        <l-popup :content="popup" :options="{ autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false }"></l-popup>
      </l-marker>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker, LIcon, LPopup } from "vue2-leaflet";
import beer from "../assets/beer-mug-icon-png-11.jpg";
export default {
  components: { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker, LIcon, LPopup },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 10,
      center: null,
      url:
        "https://tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=3eeffe78d4454d8ab83cbb1f08f30619",
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      marker: L.latLng(47.41322, -1.219482),
      icon: beer,
      iconSize: [55, 55],
      location: null,
      gettingLocation: false,
      errorStr: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getCoords() {
      let lat = parseInt(this.$store.state.beers.latitude);
      let long = this.$store.state.beers.longitude;
      console.log(this.$store.state.beers.latitude);
      this.center = L.latLng(lat, long);
      return L.latLng(lat, long);
    },

    popup() {
      return `<div><h2>${
        this.$store.state.beers.name
      }</h2><p class="popup-text">City: ${
        this.$store.state.beers.city
      }</p><p class="popup-text">State: ${
        this.$store.state.beers.state
      }</p><p class="popup-text">Country: ${
        this.$store.state.beers.country
      }</p><p class="popup-text">Type: ${
        this.$store.state.beers.type
      }</p><span class="popup-text">Website: <a class="popup-text" href="${
        this.$store.state.beers.website
      }"> ${this.$store.state.beers.website}</a></span></div>`;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //do we support geolocation
    if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
      this.errorStr = "Geolocation is not available.";
      return;
    }
    // get position
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      pos => {
        this.center = L.latLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        this.gettingLocation = true;
      },
      err => {
        this.gettingLocation = false;
        this.errorStr = err.message;
      }
    );
  },
  updated() {
    //do we support geolocation
    if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
      this.errorStr = "Geolocation is not available.";
      return;
    }
    // get position
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      pos => {
        this.center = L.latLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        this.gettingLocation = true;
      },
      err => {
        this.gettingLocation = false;
        this.errorStr = err.message;
      }
    );
  }
};
</script>
```

Also a demo here: https://beer-on-map.netlify.com/

Comment: Any update on this? Did you figure it out?

Comment: What exactly is not working? This looks ok to me, and works for me in Chrome